# HTML Textarea that execute SQL queries

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm wondering how I can make a `<textarea>` where I can write an SQL query, and execute it? Like PHPMyAdmin does.

Is it possible to make something like this?

Comment: AJAX the content of the textarea to a PHP file which performs the SQL query, handles the results, and serves them back to the browser.

Comment: So you're trying to create a [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) tool? In the long term, this tool is likely to do more harm than good. Please reconsider.

Comment: @Asaph You probably have right, but it's a homework for school so I have to do it anyway ^^

Comment: @Moose Thank you very much for your help, I'll check this out

Comment: @NassimElHormi Ah. I see. You must be at this school: https://xkcd.com/327/ ;)

Comment: @Asaph So you consider tools like PhpMyAdmin and SEDE to be code-injection tools? What about the interactive `mysql` command?

Comment: SQL-injection is when you allow unwanted query modifications from the client. If the whole purpose of the tool is to execute user-given queries, it's not SQL-injection.

Comment: @Barmar The risk of malicious use of web-based SQL consoles is not insignificant. PhpMyAdmin in particular, I would advise not having installed in production environments because it's web-based. One weak password, misconfigured firewall rule, or vulnerability in the PhpMyAdmin codebase and your business and customers at great risk. And besides malicious use, even poorly performing ad-hoc user queries can cause production problems. Just IMO.

Comment: @Asaph Of course, but we're not talking about a production environment, we're talking about an academic exercise.

Comment: @Barmar I guess I just don't like the exercise. It smells bad. I hope the student doesn't walk away from this exercise under the impression that they should ever build a tool like this for a company they might work for. I also feel a community responsibility to mention SQL Injection risk any time I see a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. You create a POST form with a textarea + submit button, e.g.
2. Fetch the POST value from the textarea: $sql = $_POST[ 'sql' ];
3. Use this value as your query
4. Execute the query :  e.g. $PDO->query($sql)->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

Of course you can use MySQLi, mysql or another library - this example was on PDO :)

And you have later also to escape some entries, if you want to prevent e.g. SQL injections. But if you're doing it only for yourself, the 4 steps above should be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it :D I come back to you if I have questions